# ng2-image-viewer is not compatible with latest version of angular (11+)

Tags: angular, image-viewer

I'm getting this error on ng serve:

ERROR in node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/index.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of SharedModule, but could not be resolved to a NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.

This likely means that the library (ng2-image-viewer) which declares ImageViewerModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also, consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Comment: This `ng2-image-viewer` is only compatible with up to Angular 5.  I would abandon this plugin and look for another one - it is not being maintained.

Comment: The same action has been taken here, though it was a good plugin but no maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **ng2-image-viewer** package has not been updated since angular version 7, therefore, it is no more usable with higher versions of angular.

a better alternative can be the **ngx-doc-viewer** package, with a little bit of difference with **ng2-image-viewer**.

I hope this answer will give a perfect alternative to those trying to use ng2-image-viewer in their applications.